# How to display label from many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have got a main table called Item, which is connected to table Label with many-to-many relationship. I would like to display the label in the view, but it doesnt work. I have tried item.label.name which gives value `None` and item.label gives `core.Label.None`. What would be the right way to display the label?

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  item_list = item_list.annotate(
      current_price=Coalesce('discount_price', 'price'))

  category_list = Category.objects.all()
  label_list = Label.objects.all()

  query = request.GET.get('q')

  if query:
      item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

  cat = request.GET.get('cat')
  if cat:
      item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=cat)

  price_from = request.GET.get('price_from')
  price_to = request.GET.get('price_to')

  if price_from:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__gte=price_from)

  if price_to:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__lte=price_to)

  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'items': items,
      'category': category_list,
      'label': label_list
  }
  return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

hmtl template:

```
                {% for item in items %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                <div class="card">

                    <div class="view overlay">
                        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="card-img-top">
                        <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body text-center">

                        <h5>
                            <strong>
                                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ item.title }}

                                    <span class="badge badge-pill "></span>
                                    <p>{{ item.label }}</p>
                                </a>

                            </strong>
                        </h5>

                        <h4 class="font-weight-bold blue-text">
                            <strong>
                                {% if item.discount_price %}
                                <strike>£{{ item.price }}</strike> £{{ item.discount_price }}
                                {% else %}
                                £{{ item.price }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </strong>
                        </h4>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price = models.FloatField()
  discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
  label = models.ManyToManyField(Label, blank=True)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  description = models.TextField()
  image = models.ImageField()

class Label(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use below thing in template to get all labels from the item because it is M2M relationship.

```
                          <h5>
                            <strong>
                                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="dark-grey-text">{{ item.title }}

                                    <span class="badge badge-pill "></span>
                                   {% for label_name in item.label.all  %} 
                                   <p>{{label_name.name}}</p>
                                   {% endfor %}
                                </a>

                            </strong>
                        </h5>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your answer: It should be "label" not "lable"

Comment: One more typo, should be {% endfor %} instead of {% enfor %}, other than that everything is fine, thanks.